# PQt4 QDatetime: Why do I get the same answer when using addSecs() with two different seconds values?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qdatetime

I'm using Python 2.6.6 and PyQt4. I have a start QDateTime object and I am iteratively adding 60 seconds to create a list of every minute within a given time span. I have discovered that there are several cases where adding two different *seconds* values to the QDateTime object produces the same time.

Here's an example of the problem:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore

start = QtCore.QDateTime.fromString("2010-11-01 00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")

print start.addSecs(522540).toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")
print start.addSecs(526140).toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")
```

And the resulting output:

```
2010-11-07 01:09
2010-11-07 01:09
```

I've been banging my head on the keyboard trying to figure this out. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: i get `2010-11-07 01:09` and `2010-11-07 02:09` - two different values

Comment: If I use QTime objects I get `01:09` and `02:09` when adding those seconds values. Otherwise it's always just as the question states.

Comment: I used the code from your question, i.e. `QDateTime`

Comment: :( I've even tried with Python 2.7.2 with the same result. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it probably depends on your locale settings:

seems [DST in the United States and other countries](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2010.html) ended on `2010-11-07`...

so i'd bet it's a result of that.

if you get any strange values from doing calculations with dates, always check if there hasn't been DST change or a leap year and consider different locales. sadly time isn't always as linear as it seems.